# Iterate JSTL var on button click

Tags: jsp, jstl

When an html button is clicked I want to increase the value of index.

```
<c:set var="index" value="${0}">
```

I tried:

```
<button id="next" onclick="<c:set var="cardIndex" scope="session" value="${cardIndex + 1}"></c:set>">Next</button>
```

but no luck. How should I do this ?

Comment: You can only get jstl value in javascript but can not set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can't. `jstl` is executed on server side while your `javascript` (along with the html sent by the server to your client) will be executed by the browser. You can still do so something with the client side values obviously, but you have to post your data to the server by submitting an http request.